# How to verify whether I have updated from beta to stable?

Tags: upgrade

I has been using Ubuntu 11 Beta, I want to verify I have the stable version. I read that I should use update manager to update, and read that the was supposed to be an "upgrade platform" or similar button, something I used when I updated from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11 beta. But this time, I dont see that, just normal updates. I tried

```
cat /etc/issue 
Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l
```

Is it the latest?

Comment: `lsb_release -a` or System > Administration > System Monitor (tab 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time there will be no "upgrade platform" button. Just normal updates. That's OK though, if you installed all updates, your ubuntu will be the stable release. That's because the transition from 11.04 beta and 11.04 stable is smooth, and there are no major system changes nedded, just few normal updates.

Answer (score 3):

When shifting from the BETA release of Ubuntu to the current release there is no upgrade process - all that happens is an update of the packages. You can verify that you've "upgraded" by simply running the Update Manager and refreshing it for a check

System > Administration > Update Manager

Alternatively you can open a Terminal and at the prompt type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That will make sure you've fetched the latest updates from the repositories, then perform any available upgrades.