# How to upgrade 12.10 beta 2 version to 12.10 final release

Tags: apt, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to verify I have updated from Ubuntu 11 beta to stable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38414/how-to-verify-i-have-updated-from-ubuntu-11-beta-to-stable)

I want to upgrade 12.10 beta 2 version to final release of ubuntu 12.10 eagerly waiting. Pls do help me.